# pass function from parent controller to directive with parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'd like to ask about the way to pass a function from controller to directive in AngularJS.

There are 2 foo in parent controller those are working almost the same (has some little different in real code) so I decided to put them in the parent controller and pass variable/function to the directive.

There are no problem with the function those have no parameter but function like `$scope.func1 = function(index) { // bla bla }` could not be passed to the directive.

Could you please help me to figure out this problem?

Any suggestion and solution are all welcome :)

### View and Controller

**view.html**

```
<my-directive lists="foo1" 
              item-click="showFoo1List()" 
              show="showFoo1" 
              func="func1"> <!-- I want to pass this one -->
</my-directive>
<my-directive lists="foo2" 
              item-click="showFoo2List()" 
              show="showFoo2" 
              func="func2">  <!-- this one -->
</my-directive>
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  // Foo1
  $scope.foo1 = [ { name: 'A'}, { name: 'B'} ]
  $scope.showFoo1 = false
  $scope.showFoo1List = function() { 
    $scope.showFoo1 = true 
  }
  $scope.func1 = function(index) { 
    console.log($scope.foo1[index]) 
    $scope.showFoo1 = false
  }
  
  // Foo2
  $scope.foo2 = [ { name: 'Y'}, { name: 'Z'} ]
  $scope.showFoo2 = false
  $scope.showFoo2List = function() { 
    $scope.showFoo2 = true 
  }
  $scope.func2 = function(index) { 
    console.log($scope.foo2[index]) 
    $scope.showFoo2 = false
  }
})
```

### Directive

**my-directive.js**

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('myDirective',
  function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        lists: '=',
        showFoo: '&',
        show: '=',
        func: '&' // pass the function(param) to here
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    }
  }
)
```

**my-directive.html**

```
<button ng-click="showFoo()">
  click me
</button>
<div ng-repeat="item in lists" 
     ng-show="show"
     ng-click="func($index)"> <!-- here it refers to func1(index) or func2(index) in parent controller -->
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

## Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to answering this question is the way how you map attributes. If you want to pass reference you have to use "=" char in your directive scope, and pass function to the directive without invoking it. If you use '&' char, Angular creates a function which wraps an expression which you pass as attribute.

Try this:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('myDirective',
  function(){
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      scope: {
        lists: '=',
        showFoo: '=',
        show: '=',
        func: '=' // pass the function(param) to here
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-directive.html',
    }
  }
)

<my-directive lists="foo2" 
          item-click="showFoo2List()" 
          show-foo="showFoo2" 
          func="func2">  <!-- this one -->
</my-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this for more information. It will be useful for your future development.

[AngularDirectives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thank you :) I'll definitely take a look! I read it but I used it wrong, hahah. Before asking, I tried using ```'='``` instead of ```'&'``` but I pass the wrong function reference (using ```'func=func1(index)``` or ```'func=func2(index)``` ) so it was not work. But everything is working good now :) Appreciate!